# What value should I choose as length for timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes, timestamp

I'm currently setting up a database to populate it with big data. All the data I get comes from Valve's Steam Web API. Therefore, as all timestamps are returned in Unix timestamps, I cannot directly derive the correct timezone - which is also not of any interest as it's to fine-grained for what it is intended for. However, PostgreSQL enables the "length"-value field when setting the column up for timestamp without timezone but I don't know which value is meaningful to enter here and I also couldn't find any information about this value - neither in the official documentation nor on StackExchange so far.

As I'm someone who doesn't set up databases all the time I'm a bit confused and would love to get some assistance. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and input.

Comment: see this answer in SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903619/5193536

Answer (score 4):

It's not the "length", it's the *precision* of the timestamp, so it controls the fractional seconds (milliseconds, microseconds) you can store.

e.g. `'2020-12-14 23:14:10.123456'::timestamp(0)` returns `2020-12-14 23:14:10` and `'2020-12-14 23:14:10.123456'::timestamp(3)` returns `2020-12-14 23:14:10.123`

As you get a unix epoch which has no fractional seconds, `timestamp(0)` should be OK.

But in the end it doesn't matter, as changing the precision doesn't change the storage requirements. It's always 8 byte regardless of the precision you choose.